# How to download a zip file from a url and extract it on windows phone 8 .The zip file contains compressed sqlite files from server

Tags: windows-phone-8, zip

I am not able to use DownloadDataAsync method.The only option present is DownloadStringAsync method.How can I download a zip file using this method.(I am new to windows phone 8 app development)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought to share the solution that worked for me.
I created a web request to the url given and downloaded the gzip file into isolated storage file.Now after downloading i created a destination file stream and stored the compressed gzip stream file from source file to destination file using WriteByte method of GZipStream.Now we get uncompressed file.

Note:-GZipStream can be added to Visual studio from NuGet manager.

Here is the code snippet which i used to download and extract GZip file.

public async Task DownloadZipFile(Uri fileAdress, string fileName)
 {
            try
            {

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileAdress);
            if (request != null)
            {
                WebResponse webResponse = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                if (webResponse.ContentLength != 0)
                {
                    using (Stream response = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (response.Length != 0)
                        {
                            using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                            {
                                if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                                    isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
                                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName))
                                {
                                    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100 * 1024;
                                    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                                    int bytesread;
                                    while ((bytesread = await response.ReadAsync(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                                    {
                                        file.Write(buf, 0, bytesread);
                                    }
                                    file.Close();

                                    FileStream sourceFileStream = File.OpenRead(file.Name);
                                    FileStream destFileStream = File.Create(AppResources.OpenZipFileName);

                                    GZipStream decompressingStream = new GZipStream(sourceFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
                                    int byteRead;
                                    while ((byteRead = decompressingStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
                                    {
                                        destFileStream.WriteByte((byte)byteRead);
                                    }
                                    decompressingStream.Close();
                                    sourceFileStream.Close();
                                    destFileStream.Close();
                                    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["DestinationFilePath"] = destFileStream.Name;
                                }
                            }
                            FileDownload = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (FileDownload == true)
            {
                return DownloadStatus.Ok;
            }
            else
            {
                return DownloadStatus.Other;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return DownloadStatus.Other;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you must use DownloadStrringAsync method? otherwise you can check these:

[How to extract zipped file received from HttpWebResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350670/how-to-extract-zipped-file-received-from-httpwebresponse)

[download and decompress a zip file in windows phone 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852710/download-and-decompress-a-zip-file-in-windows-phone-8-application)

[Extract zip file from isolatedstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742348/extract-zip-file-from-isolatedstorage)

[How to download a GZIP file from web to Windows Phone 7 and unzip the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707917/how-to-download-a-gzip-file-from-web-to-windows-phone-7-and-unzip-the-contents)

Answer (score -1):

To download zip file from the url first there is need to store zip files into isolated storage and after that extract it and read the file as per requirement.

http://axilis.hr/uznip-archives-windows-phone